# Reference 'this' in dynamic event handler

Tags: c#, reflection, event-handling, cil, reflection.emit

In my 'myClass' class, I am using Reflection.Emit to dynamically write an event handler for one of the myClass class' members.

I have done this successfully.

Now, I want to modify the event handler to call one of the instance methods in the myClass class.

However, I cannot figure out how to push a reference to 'this' onto the MSIL stack using Reflection.Emit. Within the event handler, Ldarg_0 is not a reference to 'this', but rather the first parameter of the event handler.

Does anyone know how to push a reference to 'this' on the stack so that I can call an instance method. For example, this is what I would want the c# code to look like:

```
public class myClass
{
private myObj1 obj1;
public myClass() {
   this.init();
}

private void init()
{
   obj1.myEvent += new myEvent_EventHandler(theHandler);
}

private void theHandler(myObj2 obj2, myObj3 obj3)
{
   // this is the part I'm having trouble with
   this.myFunction(obj2);
}

private void myFunction(myObj2 obj2)
{
   // irrelevant
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "Main" are you referring to an actual class or the `static void main` method that starts a program? It looks like there is some confusion based on Jakers' answer.

Comment: Sorry, poor choice. I'll revise

Comment: You cannot call an instance method from a static method as there is no instance to call it upon.

Comment: Nothing here is static, I wrote a code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Reflection.Emit` (and I'm presuming `DynamicMethod` here), **you** get to choose what the first argument to the generated code will be, and it can be passed implicitly by the delegate, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class App
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DynamicMethod m = new DynamicMethod("test", typeof(void),
            new[] { typeof(App), // <-- type of first argument, your choice
                typeof(string) });

        var cg = m.GetILGenerator();

        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        cg.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(App).GetMethod("ShowString"), null);

        cg.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Action<string> d = (Action<string>) 
            m.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<string>), 
            new App()); // <-- this is the first argument, *your* choice

        MyEvent += d;

        // Trigger event
        MyEvent("Hello there");
    }

    static event Action<string> MyEvent;

    public void ShowString(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the perfect answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

If you are in main, then there is no instance of your Main class.  The main function is static.