# Call a method when a generic event occurs

Tags: c#, events, delegates, dynamicmethod, ilgenerator

I'm facing a problem when trying to implement a call to a method fired up by an event which should be defined during run-time. I found this answer:

[Redirecting to a dynamic method from a generic event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887200/redirecting-to-a-dynamic-method-from-a-generic-event-handler)

and implemented that solution, but I keep getting an exception when the method to call is an instance one, not static.
Here is my partial code:

```
public class Operation
{
    public bool EventFired 
    {
        get { return _eventFired; }
    }

    private bool _eventFired = false;

    public void Execute(object source, string EventName)
    {
        EventInfo eventInfo = source.GetType().GetEvent(EventName);
        Delegate handler = null;

        Type delegateHandler = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        MethodInfo invokeMethod = delegateHandler.GetMethod("Invoke");
        ParameterInfo[] parms = invokeMethod.GetParameters();

        Type[] parmTypes = new Type[parms.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < parms.Length; i++)
            parmTypes[i] = parms[i].ParameterType;

        DynamicMethod customMethod = new DynamicMethod
            (
            "TempMethod",
            invokeMethod.ReturnType,
            parmTypes,
            typeof (Operation).Module
            );

        MethodInfo inf = typeof (Operation).GetMethod("SetFlag", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        ILGenerator ilgen = customMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, inf);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        //handler = _customMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateHandler);          // This works if I change SetFlag() to static 

        handler = customMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateHandler, this);       // I get an ArgumentException at this point: 
                                                                            //Cannot bind to the target method because its signature 
                                                                            //or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.   



        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(source, handler);
    }

    /// <summary>Signals that the event has been raised.</summary>
    public void SetFlag()
    {
        _eventFired = true;
    }

}
```

I can't find a way to get rid of that exception, the code works fine if I turn **SetFlag()** method to static, but that's not what I need.
Any suggestions would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate (or at least related question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865848/general-purpose-fromevent-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve the problem by slightly modifying the DynamicMethod definition, as described in this answer:

[Reference 'this' in dynamic event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121060/reference-this-in-dynamic-event-handler?lq=1)

If I add my class type as first value in the **Type** array, which is then passed as parameter to the DynamicMethod, the delegate is correctly created and it works with instance methods!

```
public class Operation
{
    public bool EventFired 
    {
        get { return _eventFired; }
    }

    private bool _eventFired = false;

    public void Execute(object source, string EventName)
    {
        EventInfo eventInfo = source.GetType().GetEvent(EventName);
        Delegate handler = null;

        Type delegateHandler = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;
        MethodInfo invokeMethod = delegateHandler.GetMethod("Invoke");
        ParameterInfo[] parms = invokeMethod.GetParameters();

        Type[] parmTypes = new Type[parms.Length + 1];

        parmTypes[0] = this.GetType();  //First parameter is this class type.

        for (int i = 0; i < parms.Length; i++)
            parmTypes[i + 1] = parms[i].ParameterType;

        DynamicMethod customMethod = new DynamicMethod
                                    (
                                        "TempMethod",
                                        invokeMethod.ReturnType,
                                        parmTypes
                                    );

        MethodInfo inf = typeof (Operation).GetMethod("SetFlag", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        ILGenerator ilgen = customMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, inf);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        handler = customMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateHandler, this);      

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(source, handler);
    }

    /// <summary>Signals that the event has been raised.</summary>
    public void SetFlag()
    {
        _eventFired = true;
    }

}
```